# Saving captured picture to photo library in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I know how to save the captured photo to the library but I added some extra code because I wanted the label in my camera view to combine together and save. When I try to save it to the photo library it doesn't save with the label. Here is the code I have:

```
@IBAction func takePicture(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
                let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.previewCamera.bounds.size, self.previewCamera.opaque, 0.0)
                self.previewCamera.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                self.capturedImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()               
                //saves captured picture to camera roll.
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you're modifying `self.capturedImage` instead of `image`, but saving `image` to the photo library.

Comment: I tried doing image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCureentImageContext() and I get an error.

Comment: @sschale Any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: Can anyone please help me?